# Check For Uniqueness in Array, Push To Array if Unique

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, push

Using AngularJS, I'm creating an addTodo function in my app.

I seem to be having trouble implementing a way to check the uniqueness of the object being added to the array, and having it followed by additional actions.

So far I'm able to get the additional actions working, but not the initial check for uniqueness. How can I implement the check for uniqueness action and then have it followed by the additional actions?

The addTodo function I'm trying to create flows like this (**Bold** means not implemented):

1. Check if todo is already in todos

   1a.  **If it does exisit, don't push, display alert**
2. Check if todo is not blank

   2a. If it is blank, don't push, display alert
3. If unique and not blank, push to todos, display success message

Current addTodo function (without unqiueness check):

```
$scope.addTodo = function(){
  $scope.isVisible = true;
  if ($scope.todo) {
    $scope.todos.push($scope.todo);
    $scope.todo = '';
    $scope.alert = $scope.alerts[1];
  }else{
    $scope.alert = $scope.alerts[0];
  }
};
```

*Note 1: `$scope.alert` and `$scope.alerts` are used to display certain error messages;*

```
$scope.alerts[0]
```

"Please add text to your task."

```
$scope.alerts[1]
```

"Added a new task!"

The alert I want to display if the task being added already exists is

```
$scope.alerts[3]
```

"Task already in list."

*Note 2: `$scope.isVisible` toggles the visibility of the alert*

Comment: So `todo` is a simple string or an object?

Comment: It's a simple string, yes

Comment: Hope you have checked my answer then.

Comment: I have, thank you! Adding a comment to it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) this way:

```
$scope.addTodo = function(){
  $scope.isVisible = true;
  if ($scope.todo) {
    if ($scope.todos.indexOf($scope.todo) == -1) {
        $scope.todos.push($scope.todo);
        $scope.todo = '';
        $scope.alert = $scope.alerts[1];
    }else{
     // $scope.todo is already in the $scope.todos array, alert the user
        $scope.alert = $scope.alerts[3];
    }
  }else{
    $scope.alert = $scope.alerts[0];
  }
};
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Solved my main issues of not being sure where in the flow to implement the action and how to properly implement it based on what I already had.

Comment: _Note for others:_ mef's flow differs from the flow I established above, but is actually the correct way to look at it: First, check if the todo is blank. If it isn't, THEN check if it is unique. My pitfall in the code below was I was too attached to the idea that I needed to check if the todo was unique first before checking if it was blank.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) OR [lodash](https://lodash.com/), you can use this simple code to push unique items in array.

```
if (_.findWhere($scope.todos, $scope.todo) == null) {
    $scope.todos.push($scope.todo);
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a standard string `todo` you can use the javascript array [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) method. This method for object data types does a reference match.

Else you can also look at jquery [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) method.

Use one of these methods to check if `$scope.todos` already contains such element and show the alert.

Comment: Based on that, I've edited the code like this, but it's still allowing duplicates to be pushed to the array;

`$scope.addTodo = function(){
$scope.isVisible = true;
var todos = $scope.todos;
var todo = $scope.todo;
if (todo == todos.indexOf(todo)){
$scope.alert = $scope.alerts[3];
} else if ($scope.todo) {
$scope.todos.push($scope.todo);
$scope.todo = '';
$scope.alert = $scope.alerts[1];
} else {
$scope.alert = $scope.alerts[0];
}
};`